# Google Chart json data feed

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

i'm using google piechart api and i need to data feed with google DataTable.

i have an ajax callback in page.. after callback i m parsing json data and i need to set google dataTable while json parsing. and i need to call drawChart() function with this datatable parameter.

How can i set google datatable in jquery each function ?

```
var googleData= new google.visualization.DataTable();
    googleData.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    googleData.addColumn('number', 'Slices');


$.ajax({
   url: 'getCharData.aspx',
   success: function(data) {
     $.each(data.GeneralData, function (i, item) {

         .... need to set googleData rows with jsondata....

     });
     drawChart(googleData); 
   }
 });




  google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['piechart'] });

  function drawPieChart(data) {
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'))
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Set colors on google piechart via dataTable JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064929/set-colors-on-google-piechart-via-datatable-json) for the structure of the javascript and the wrapper. Also the format of the data required to be returned by the server to produce a piechart.

Be careful that you're .aspx page isn't returning actual .

General points;

- The column data needs to be beside the row data in the JSON
- Use the ChartWrapper, as it allows you to separate out he set-up from the rendering nicely.