# Set colors on google piechart via dataTable JSON

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am using the chartWrapper to pull in some JSON. I am wondering how I would go about settings the colours for each segment on the piechart.

```
//draw the channel summary data
 $.getJSON("@Url.Action("SummaryData", new { id = Model.Id })", function(data) {
     var channelChartWrapper = new window.google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         chartType: "PieChart",
         dataTable: data,
         options: {
             title: "Title here"
         },
         containerId: "summary-chart",
     });
     channelChartWrapper.draw();
 });
```

the data returned by the controller looks like this;

```
{
   "cols":[
      {
         "id":"",
         "label":"Channel",
         "type":"string",
         "pattern":""
      },
      {
         "id":"",
         "label":"Value",
         "type":"number",
         "pattern":""
      }
   ],
   "rows":[
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"A",
               "f":null
            },
            {
               "v":17,
               "f":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"B",
               "f":null
            },
            {
               "v":208,
               "f":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"C",
               "f":null
            },
            {
               "v":4,
               "f":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "v":"D",
               "f":null
            },
            {
               "v":2,
               "f":null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried various `p: { style: "color: pink" }` additions to the cells but with no luck. I can get colours using the `colors` property on the chart, but this isn't going to work for me as the colour is specifc to the data.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can't set colours for charts (different story for tables) in the DataTable/JSON explicitly. However, you can hack around it slightly.

```
{
   cols:[...,]
   rows:[...,]
   p:{
      colors: ["#ffcc00","#ff0000",...]
   }
}
```

Then in the javascript;

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("SummaryData", new { id = Model.Id })", function(data) {
     var channelChartWrapper = new window.google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         chartType: "PieChart",
         dataTable: data,
         options: {
             title: "Title here",
             colors: data.p.colors
         },
         containerId: "summary-chart",
     });
     channelChartWrapper.draw();
 });
```